# VBA confusion regarding IF

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Simple fault probably but I can´t find the error. The code belows says one of my "else" has no "if". But I cant find out why...

Help please :)

whether i missed to add `end if` or some other problem?

```
Sub In_knapp_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim g As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long

b = 3

For a = 1 To 7 Step 1

    If Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) = a Then

                     For g = 3 To 12 Step 2

                        If g = 11 Then
                        MsgBox "Ingen Ut tid hittades"
                        Exit For

                        Else

                            If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Pontevedra").Cells(b, g).Value) Then

                                For i = 2 To 10 Step 2

                                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Pontevedra").Cells(b, i).Value) Then

                                        Worksheets("Pontevedra").Cells(b, i).Value = Now
                                        ButtonOneClick = True
                                        Exit For

                                    Else

                                    MsgBox "Fel"

                                    End If

                            Else

                    Next g

                    End If           
    Else
        b = b + 1  
End If
Next a
End Sub
```

i  cant find any help

Comment: You should indent the code properly, then the mistake should become easier to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a Next I and a few End Ifs - this compiles but may not be what you are trying to do :

```
Sub In_knapp_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim g As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    b = 3
    For a = 1 To 7 Step 1
        If Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) = a Then
            For g = 3 To 12 Step 2
                If g = 11 Then
                    MsgBox "Ingen Ut tid hittades"
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Pontevedra").Cells(b, g).Value) Then
                        For i = 2 To 10 Step 2
                            If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Pontevedra").Cells(b, i).Value) Then
                                Worksheets("Pontevedra").Cells(b, i).Value = Now
                                ButtonOneClick = True
                                Exit For
                            Else
                                MsgBox "Fel"
                            End If
                        Next i
                    Else
                        ' ?
                    End If
                    '?
                End If
            Next g
        Else
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```